# How do I run a Mavin plugin with replacement variables from the project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar

I found this example:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar -DgroupId=${project.groupId} -DartifactId=${project.artifactId} -Dversion=${project.version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

It was from this post. [Installing a jar file using Intellij run configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69323560/installing-a-jar-file-using-intellij-run-configuration)

I am trying to figure out where and how to make that work in my environment.

Comment: Why not using `mvn install` ?

Comment: That's what I found after digging further. thanks